# Dynamic arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, directory

I am creating a directory traversal application for sorting emails. It is a very simple app for my specific needs.

I would like to implement this by first traversing all the email files (there are 1000's of them in a few directories) and make new directories based on the sent/received information inside the eml files (The sent or received name used will be decided based on a constant).

I was thinking something like this

```
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
    email = getEmail(file);
    emailSentRcievedName = sentRecievedName(email);
    dirArray[currentDir + "\" + emailSentRecievedName] = file.get();
    return CONTINUE;
}
```

The dirArray key:value will be used for the file moving implementation.

I know this array structure would work in Javascript but how would I implement this in Java?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you looking for `HashMap`?

Comment: Also note that what you're building isn't considered an "array" in either Java or JavaScript.

Comment: Use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: @Pointy - Actually, this is data structure commonly referred to as an *[associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)*. I've most commonly seen the term pop up when talking about PHP and JavaScript. Notice that the Wikipedia page lists a hash table (i.e. `HashMap`) as a common way of implementing the data structure, which is exactly what everyone here suggested to use.

Comment: Thanks. I think the consensus is clear. HashMap it is.

Comment: @DaoWen it is in other languages, but that terminology is not really accurate in JavaScript. A JavaScript array is a very particular thing, and it's not really possible to reproduce Array behavior outside of the runtime internals. In particular, note that there is no intrinsic "property counter" for object properties; that is, there's no direct way to get the "size" of an Object.

Comment: @Pointy - You are talking about implementation details. I know that an "associative array" isn't really an "array," just like a "priority queue" isn't really a "queue." I did a bit of digging and it looks like the term was borrowed from PHP. I'm thinking the term caught on because the syntax is identical, and now it's so common that even [json.org](http://www.json.org/) uses it as a synonym for JavaScript-style objects. You're right about it not being a very accurate term, but it's a valid term nonetheless.

Comment: @DaoWen well I don't particularly mind the term, but here on StackOverflow there are many questions about JavaScript object semantics, often asked by people familiar with associative arrays in other languages, that stem from a misunderstanding of the JavaScript implementation. Thus I try to be particular about the terminology here to avoid that sort of confusion. You are right however that the term is in common use and I agree that there's nothing inherently wrong with it for those who understand what's going on.

Comment: @Pointy - I was trying to find a way to contact you outside these comments (we've drifted a bit off-topic), but I don't see any way to do that. (I'm pretty new to StackOverflow, so there's probably something I'm missing.) Anyway, I was curious about the JavaScript implementation details you're talking about for arrays/objects. Is this in the ECMAScript spec somewhere, or are you talking about a specific implementation (e.g. V8, Rhino, SpiderMonkey)? I had no idea you couldn't directly get the "size" of an object—so some further reading might do me good.

Comment: @DaoWen [Here is a great blog post](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) that covers some of the ways that Array objects are "special" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a hashmap. It gives you the ability to store pairs of data

```
Map<String,File> map = new HashMap<String, File>();
map.put(currentdir +"/"+ emailSentReceivedName, file);

File file = map.get(path); //will give you the file
```

**Also take a look at this:** *SortedMap*, maybe it helps you 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Javadoc api here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a java.util.HashMap() instead!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
Map<String, File> map = new HashMap<String, File>();
map.put(currentdir + "\" + emailSentReceivedName, file.get());
```